# Problem in integration of a function

Tags: integration

[image]

I got the option A , as one of the answer .

But I am confused how to find other options as there integration of a function which includes a fnction itself .

Comment: Listen, I just want to say, If you want to ask question, please format it yourself using $LaTeX$, this shows that you have atleast put effort  in writing your question. Don't just post a screenshot.I just reviewed low quality post, and all of them were your's. I skipped beacause there was no violation of policy as stated in the help center. But please put effort if you want us to put effort in writing an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $f(0)=\int_0^{\pi/2}f(t)\,dt$ is a constant, real number. We hence have that

$$f(x)=1-\sin(x)-\cos(x)+\int_0^{\pi/2}f(t)\,dt$$

Substituting back into $f(t)$ inside the integral we have:

\begin{align}
f(x)&=1-\sin(x)-\cos(x)+\int_0^{\pi/2}1-\sin(t)-\cos(t)+\left(\int_0^{\pi/2}f(s)\,ds\right)\,dt\\
&=1-\sin(x)-\cos(x)+\int_0^{\pi/2}1-\sin(t)-\cos(t)\,dt+\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\int_0^{\pi/2}f(s)\,ds\right)\,dt\\
&=1-\sin(x)-\cos(x)+\frac{\pi-4}2+\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}f(s)\,ds
\end{align}

It follows that

$$1-\sin(x)-\cos(x)+\int_0^{\pi/2}f(t)\,dt=1-\sin(x)-\cos(x)+\frac{\pi-4}2+\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}f(t)\,dt\\
\implies\frac{4-\pi}2=\left(\frac\pi2-1\right)\int_0^{\pi/2}f(t)\,dt=\left(\frac{\pi-2}2\right)\int_0^{\pi/2}f(t)\,dt\\
\implies\int_0^{\pi/2}f(t)\,dt=\frac{4-\pi}{\pi-2}$$

so that finally $$f(x)=1-\sin(x)-\cos(x)+\frac{4-\pi}{\pi-2}=\frac{2}{\pi-2}-\sin(x)-\cos(x).$$ Do you think you can take it from here?

Comment: In this  $1-\sin(x)-\cos(x)+\frac{\pi-4}2+\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}f(s)\,ds$ , How do you get $\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}f(s)\,ds$

Comment: $\int_0^{\pi/2}f(s)\,ds$ is a constant, so its integral with respect to $t$ (from $0$ to $\pi/2$) is simply $\frac\pi2\int_0^{\pi/2}f(s)\,ds$.

Comment: Thanks , very nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following identities along with the solution $f(x)$ above to answer your questions.

Let $x = t + \pi/4$:
$$ \begin{align} 
\sin x &= \sin(t+\pi/4) = \frac{\sqrt2}{2} (\sin t + \cos t), \quad (1) \\
\cos x &= \cos(t+\pi/4) = \frac{\sqrt2}{2} (\cos t - \sin t). \quad (2) \\
\end{align}
$$

Identities:
$$ \begin{align} 
\sin x + \cos x &= \sqrt2 \cos(x-\pi/4), \quad (3) \\
\sin x - \cos x &= \sqrt2 \sin(x-\pi/4). \quad (4) \\
\end{align}
$$

For example, on question (A):
$$ f'(x) = \sin x -\cos x = \sqrt2 \sin(x-\pi/4). $$

Thus, $f'(x) = 0$ at $x = \pi/4, 5\pi/4$, and $f'(x) > 0$ for $\pi/4 < x < 5\pi/4$. Hence, $f(x)$ is increasing for $x$ in $(\pi/4, 5\pi/4)$.